# Read First Node from XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I receive message in XML string; that I load into `XmlDocument`; but second node is different every time; I have given example below are three examples:

```
 <Message> 
    <Event1 Operation="Amended" Id="88888">Other XML Text</Event1>
 </Message>
 <Message>
    <Event2 _Operation_="Cancelled" Id="9999999"> Other XML Text </Event2>
 </Message> 
 <Message> 
    <Event3 Operation="Cancelled" Id="22222"> Other XML Text </Event3>
 </Message>
```

Now, I want to find out whether second node is `Event1` or `Event2` or `Event3` and also what is value of Operation e.g. "Amended", "Cancelled", "Ordered" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml("<Message><Event1 Operation=\"Amended\" Id=\"88888\"> Other XML Text</Event1></Message>");
        Debug.WriteLine(xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Operation"].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument oDoc = XmlDocument.Load(yourXmlHere);
// Your message node.
XmlNode oMainNode = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Message");
// Message's first subnode (Event1, Event2, ...)
XmlNode oEventNode = oMainNode.ChildNodes[0];
// Event1, Event2, ...
string sEventNodeName = oEventNode.Name;
// Value of operation attribute.
string sOpValue = oEventNode.Attributes["Operation"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, you could check the `DocumentElement.FirstChild.Name` on the `XmlDocument` object to retrieve the name of the first child element of the Message element.

The Operation attribute can be read using `DocumentElement.FirstChild.GetAttribute("Operation").`